# Cannot set suPHP_ConfigPath for localhost

Tags: php, .htaccess, localhost

I am trying to make my **php.ini** file recursive.

```
echo php_ini_loaded_file();
```

**gives:**

```
C:\xampp\php\php.ini
```

Yet when I set in my **.htaccess file**:

```
suPHP_ConfigPath C:\xampp\php\php.ini
```

I get

> Server error! The server encountered an internal error and was unable
>   to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was
>   an error in a CGI script.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 500 localhost Apache/2.4.37 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.1 PHP/7.2.12

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

[As per guide here.](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/php/recursive-php-ini)

Comment: Did you check permissions? Error 500 is generic and would advise checking other logs or increasing the log level.

Comment: Why are you using SuPHP? Its not maintained. It forces all code to run as interpreted. Use PHP-FPM if you want to run PHP as different users.

Comment: @Twisty, error log shows:  `[Wed Jan 02 00:30:24.960427 2019] [core:alert] [pid 32488:tid 1980] [client ::1:63059] C:/xampp/htdocs/sillyharvest/.htaccess: Invalid command 'suPHP_ConfigPath', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`  What is to be made of this?

Comment: @symcbean  I'm just blindly following a [guide](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/php/recursive-php-ini) as I'm not a web administrator and have little idea what I'm doing here.  Feel free to suggest a step-by-step solution that I can follow.

Comment: You might start by reading the manual. PHP *some* PHP settings can be set directly in an htaccess file. *some* can be overridden in code. PHP-FPM allows you set multplie PHP pools, each with their own ini file.

Comment: @ptrcao this might suggest that the module is not installed to PHP. It may also suggest that the path value is incorrect, maybe it needs to be `C:\\xampp\\php\\php.ini`. Suggest reviewing: https://www.suphp.org/Documentation.html

Comment: @ptrcao does `phpinfo()` show that suPHP module is enabled?

Comment: @Twisty I can't find any reference to `suPHP` in the phpinfo() output...

Comment: Is there an alternative way to achieve [what I want](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/php/recursive-php-ini) without suPHP module?

Comment: @ptrcao that article is 2 years old and appears to be specific to inmotion hosting. If you're hosting your site elsewhere, this article may not be relevant. As was mentioned, you can use `.htaccess` in some cases. Please clarify which settings you're trying to use in different folders? You can also use `set_ini()` for some specific settings in specific scripts.

Comment: @Twisty  Basically, I'm trying to make it so that my main php.ini file in the root recursively applies to all subdirectories in the root also.

Comment: @ptrcao that should be the case already, yet it will depend on your Web Server setup. I would also advise checking with your web host admins, they can assist.

Comment: @Twisty  how can I confirm it is already the case globally?  I don't have a web admin.  I'm supposed to be the web admin, but I'm really just learning...

Comment: Take a look here: https://www.pickaweb.co.uk/kb/inherit-php-values-in-your-local-php-ini-to-all-subdirectories/

Comment: @ptrcao based on the above, it appears the path need to be to a folder and not the ini itself.